# HtmlAgilityPack - doesn't load all images

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get an image from a web site.

```
HtmlWeb html = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument htmldoc = html.Load("http://www.inc.com/christine-lagorio/fashion-week-wearable-technology.html");
var img = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='articleheaderimage']/img");
```

The problem is that img is null although it's inside the HTML.

So I went to check the figure tag InnerHtml.

```
var figure = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//figure");
```

It seems that the img tag converted to white space.

Here is some of the InnerHtml

```
<div id="articleheaderimage" class="picture inc_editable inc_editable_image" data-editor-class="ImageEditor" data-label="Main Image" data-content-type="article" data-content-id="61627" data-fieldname="image" data-parent-id="wrappercontainer">
<!-- the image tag supposed to be here -->
<span class="smallest small-between-medium" data-src="http://www.inc.com/uploaded_files/image/640x290/wearable-technology_39857.jpg" data-src-x2="http://www.inc.com/uploaded_files/image/640x290/wearable-technology_39857.jpg"></span>
```

What do i need to do to get the img tag?

Comment: ***Right click the page and "View page source" and make sure it does show within the source code*** and not just in the developers tool, what the developers tool shows you is different than what the source code can be as the developers tool will render JavaScript and other things that can dynamically generate content to the page.

Comment: You're right it's not in the source.
Is there a way to load the html after JavaScript has finished?

Comment: No, not with HTMLAgilityPack alone, there are of course ways to process JS and other ways to deal with it for instance using a browser element to render the page and read from it or simple checking the requests to see what loads the content you want and reading from there, there are also other ways.